# Server Sent Events in Golang - Browser only get event stream on localhost

Tags: javascript, go, localhost, server-sent-events

I try Server Sent Events with golang. I use the library described here: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/writing-a-server-sent-events-server-in-go

I got it working but only with localhost but if I use my hostname in the address line of my browser it doesnt work. It also doesn't work if I call the website on another client.

I tried something to solve it. If I send some SSE to the client and kill the server application then all sent events arrive the browser application at once.
If I use curl it works:

```
curl -v myhost:8081/updates
*   Trying ....
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to myhost (...) port 8081 (#0)
> GET /updates HTTP/1.1
> Host: myhost:8081
> User-Agent: curl/7.50.3
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: text/event-stream
< Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2019 17:07:27 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
data: {"X":127,"Y":227,"Zeitpunkt":"29.11.2019 18:07:27"}

data: {"X":128,"Y":228,"Zeitpunkt":"29.11.2019 18:07:28"}

data: {"X":128,"Y":228,"Zeitpunkt":"29.11.2019 18:07:29"}
```

What could be the problem? I use the newest golang library

Here is my javascript code:

```
  <script>
    if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
        var source = new EventSource("updates");
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
            var pmstat = jQuery.parseJSON(event.data);
            $('#bestandX').html(pmstat.X);
            $('#bestandY').html(pmstat.Y);
            $('#aktualisiertAm').html(pmstat.Zeitpunkt);
        };

    } else {
        $('body').html('<h1 style="color: red">Browser unterstützt keine Server-sent events.</h1>')
    }
  </script>
```

and here is the golang code I use from the library:

```
// Implement the http.Handler interface.
// This allows us to wrap HTTP handlers (see auth_handler.go)
// http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler
func (broker *Broker) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // Make sure that the writer supports flushing.
    //
    flusher, ok := rw.(http.Flusher)

    if !ok {
        http.Error(rw, "Streaming unsupported!", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Set the headers related to event streaming.
    rw.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
    rw.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    rw.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
    rw.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    // Each connection registers its own message channel with the Broker's connections registry
    messageChan := make(MessageChan)

    // Signal the broker that we have a new connection
    broker.newClients <- messageChan

    // Remove this client from the map of connected clients
    // when this handler exits.
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("HERE.")
        broker.closingClients <- messageChan
    }()

    // "raw" query string option
    // If provided, send raw JSON lines instead of SSE-compliant strings.
    req.ParseForm()
    raw := len(req.Form["raw"]) > 0

    // Listen to connection close and un-register messageChan
    notify := rw.(http.CloseNotifier).CloseNotify()

    go func() {
        <-notify
        broker.closingClients <- messageChan
    }()

    // block waiting or messages broadcast on this connection's messageChan
    for {
        // Write to the ResponseWriter
        if raw {
            // Raw JSON events, one per line
            fmt.Fprintf(rw, "%s\n", <-messageChan)
        } else {
            // Server Sent Events compatible
            fmt.Fprintf(rw, "data: %s\n\n", <-messageChan)
        }
        // Flush the data inmediatly instead of buffering it for later.
        flusher.Flush()

    }
}
```

I tried this library and the same happens here:
https://github.com/alexandrevicenzi/go-sse

Now I tried to close the connection after every message and give the browser the command to reconnect immediately. Here are the two lines I added in the code:

```
...
    go func() {
        <-notify
        broker.closingClients <- messageChan
    }()

    // block waiting or messages broadcast on this connection's messageChan
    for {
        // Write to the ResponseWriter
        if raw {
            // Raw JSON events, one per line
            fmt.Fprintf(rw, "%s\n", <-messageChan)
        } else {
            // Server Sent Events compatible
            fmt.Fprintf(rw, "retry: %d\n", 0) //<--- I added this
            fmt.Fprintf(rw, "data: %s\n\n", <-messageChan)
        }
        // Flush the data inmediatly instead of buffering it for later.
        flusher.Flush()
        break //<--- I added this
    }
}
```

Now it almost works but this is only a workaround for me. Does someone have a good solution how it works while keeping the connection alive?

Comment: Confirm that the url "updates" makes sense in all scenarios.  Debugging hints: Add [onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource/onerror) handler on client and log errors.   Add logging to server loop to confirm that messages are sent (perhaps broker is broken?).

Comment: If I add onerror its never called except on killing the server when all queued messages appear

Comment: Is "Servent" a typo, or the name of something?

Comment: It is a  typo :)